# Coredata upgrade fails when only attribute type is upgraded

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I am using following code for automatic migration in coredata.

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

This is the version1 code for the entity class.

```
@interface Entity :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * var;

@end
```

Following is the version2 code

```
    @interface Entity :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * var;

@end
```

In verision only attribute type of var is changed from NSString to NSDate

Let me know if anything else needs to be done if only attribute type is changed..

It works fine if i add other classes or new attributes to the version2 coredata.

Regards,
Dhana

Comment: How does it fail? I did this recently, and it worked fine.

Comment: It occurs when i upgrade the aplicaation from old version to latest version.

Comment: It occurs when i upgrade the application from old version to latest version. Following is the error ------  logsUnresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134140.)" UserInfo=0x7883ae0 {reason=Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration, destinationModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6390e50>) isEditable 0, entities

Comment: I am changing the attribute type. i.e. from NSString to NSDate.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem @Dhanaraj? I am currently trying to do something similar but using a custom heavy migration.

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow the proper procedure to implement the core data model version change in Xcode 4.2. Check out in particular:

- [Adding a new version to a Managed Object Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH8-SW1)
- and [Setting a Managed Object Model’s Current Version](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/setting_current_version.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH9-SW1)

It will also help to completely delete the app from the simulator or your device before running the new version.

Comment: I already have the application in appstore, so i can not delete the old database. And updating works in all cases except change of attribute type.

Comment: Why did you down vote? This procedure does indeed ensure that the data remains intact. You have to write your own coding routine to convert from string to date.